# Cannot set up right CRS in gvSIG

Tags: gvsig

I have a problem in gvSIG. I imported datas from OpenStreetMap using osm2pgsql. I do use them everyday with QGIS, it works perfectly.
In QGis, the CRS is set to 32630 (WGS 84 UTM zone 30N) +proj=utm +zone=30 +ellps=WGS84 +datum=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs +towgs84=0,0,0

When I want to connect to the same database with QGIS, if I use the default WGS 84 4326 it works well bit the datas are displayed in oblique which sounds normal, it does the same in QGIS. But here is my problem, when i set up a CRS in 32630 in gvSIG it doesn't work … I will get a crappy animation of big objects all over the map that are slowing down the software …
If I change the CRS after, I dot have nothing displayed and using the icon to zoom over the data areas does nothing.

here is a screen shot of the result using 32630 CRS.

https://www.box.com/s/731pqcpa3szkrzun6i1f
https://www.box.com/s/l1to0a36rpqqmk29nm2n

Comment: Which version of gvSIG are you using?

Are you setting your view CRS on 32630 and then setting your database data source CRS in 4326?

Comment: I am using gvSIG 1.11.0 RC1 for Mac OS X. Yes I set the base in 4326 cos'I use osm2pgsql to import the datas in Postgis. The base has been created 1 year ago and I use it almost everyday in QGIS without any problem.